# Programmatically transitioning between two UIViewControllers (Xcode 9, Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

The app I am currently working on requires that I do not use ANY storyboards. Therefore I need to do everything programmatically. One thing I seem to be struggling with is switching between two UIViewControllers.

The issue is that every time I call the `self.present()` method; it creates a brand new instance of the class I would like to show. So when I go into Xcode's visual debugger, I see over 15 different views that are all stacked and are merely instantiations of one another. Ex: View1, View2, View1, View2, View1, View2, View1... This constant repetition of the views is significantly hurting the performance of my app. So my question:

**Is there a way that I can switch between my two UIViewControllers without constantly creating a new instance of each one?**

*Again, I am doing all of this with ALL storyboards DELETED. So the solution I necessary needs to be implemented using ONLY code.*

Comment: Instead of presenting view1 from view2, why not just dismiss view2 so the original view1 is visible again?

Comment: @rmaddy, what code would I implement to make the dismissal possible?

Comment: @SidKumar `self.dismiss()`?

Comment: @Tj3n Thank you!

Comment: Please read *Present* - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present 
*Dismiss* - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create main ViewController.

if you keep your two instance view controller, create two controller in mainViewController. Then keep that in main viewController.

And push view controller you want to present in navigation of main view controller
if you want to change second view controller pop navigation controller and push another, or just push other controller.

if you want keep your instance view controller i think it's best option for you

Comment: Main view controller can be empty. just create create two view controller and keep that instance alive.

Answer (score -2):

I think that it is really important to realize the fact that the view controller will show up multiple times in the debugger because that is something that can throw off the performance of the app. I really like the way you mention that in your comment. This is one of the main differences that can outstand you from another programmer in the same field. One of the most easiest and simple ways to fix this problem would be using the self.dismiss() method. Another way to dismiss this view controller would be to use a navigation controller to fix this problem. A navigation controller will push the main view controller out of the way and it will not create multiple instances of it. This will be the most efficient as it doesn't require a lot of code and a mere initialization of the UINavigationController class implemented in the UIKit. This is one of the most important tools and resources that you must make use of while coding in xcode and developing your skills in the swift ios field. Since this problem is not one of the most common to find on the internet, it is very beneficial for you to post it on this forum page and will really be helpful for some other programmers unaware of such methods and ways to code. One of the questions that I have for you is the fact that you don't want to use storyboards. Why don't you want to use storyboards and only make it proGrAMitcally? This is one of the very questions that manages to astound me. The storyboard is an implementation that makes it very easy for xcode and swift users to work around the tedious work that has to be done while working in the coding aspect. It only takes a few lines of code and you can get a seGu done very easily. The switch is very easily done and you can find this method on some youtube channels. For this type of work, I recommend VigneshSriniswami Patel and ShaniLakshmiVishnuJiSwami, these content creators will help guide you to becoming an xcode master.

Hope I helped!